# Quantifier order confusion

Tags: proof-verification, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I wondered, if $\forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y)$ is equivalent to $\exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y)$.

If $R(x, y) = (x < y)$ then the answer would appear to be no.

In the first case, for all $x$, does there exist a $y$ such that $x < y$? Sure, just pick $y = x + 1$.

In the second case, it says there exists a $y$ such that $x < y$ holds for all $x$. But any $x$ that is greater than or equal to $y$ would make this false.

So it seems that the order of the quantifiers matter, but then we have this proof:

```
∃x ∀y R(x, y)                                 [Hypothesis]

Let c be a constant such that ∀y R(c, y)
    ∀y R(c, y)    

    Given constant d:
        R(c, d)                               [∀ elim]
        ∃x R(x, d)                            [∃ intro]

    ∀y ∃x R(x, y)                             [∀ intro]

∀y ∃x R(x, y)                                 [∃ elim]
```

Here it seems to imply we can swap the order if we start out with an exists quantifier coming first?

In other words is it true that:

$\forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y) \not\rightarrow \exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y)$ (how would we actually prove this?)

But:

$\exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y)$

Comment: Yes. If $\exists y \forall x R(x,y)$ is true then that means there is a $y_0$ that works with every $x$. So this means $R(x,y_0)$ is a true statement for all $x$, i.e. each $x$ can be paired with a $y$ (namely $y_0$) for which $R(x,y)$ is true.

Comment: You've already given a perfectly good counterexample showing that $\forall x \exists y R(x,y) \rightarrow \exists y \forall x R(x,y)$ is not a tautology.  In other words, if it were a tautology of first-order logic, then it would hold in any model; but you've given a model in which it does not hold; so you get a contradiction.  The conclusion is that it is not a tautology of FOL.

Comment: On the other hand, $\forall x \exists y R(x,y) \not\rightarrow \exists y \forall x R(x,y)$ is not a tautology, it's just not a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}}$

Okay, now, that was a valid derivation for *that* implication, but to introduce *equivalence* you also need to derive the converse; which you *cannot* do.

$$\fitch{}{\fitch{\exists x\forall y~xRy}{\fitch{[c]~\forall y~cRy}{\fitch{[u]}{cRu\\\exists x~xRu}\\\forall y~\exists x~xRy}\\\forall y~\exists x~xRy}\\\exists x~\forall y~xRy\to\forall y~\exists x~xRy\\\fitch{\forall y~\exists x~xRy}{\fitch{[u]}{\exists x~xRu\\\fitch{[c]~cRu}{...\text{cannot introduce the universal at this point}}}\\\ldots\text{cannot conclude the }\exists\forall\text{ statement}}\\\ldots\text{unable to derive the converse statememt}}$$

Now, there are interpretations of the relation $R$ for which the converse will be true, but it is not so in general.

Rather than fallaciously declaring it proven to be a not-implication ($\vdash a\nrightarrow b$), we should correctly state that it is *not proven to be an implication* ($\nvdash a\to b$).

Comment: But just because we can't find a proof in that approach doesn't mean we've proven it definitively? Couldn't we instead prove that $p \not\rightarrow q =  \lnot(p \to q) = p \land \lnot q$ is true? This was my initial approach but I don't know how you prove a conjunction since every statement in a proof is supposed to be true in its context? Somehow showing that $∀x ∃y R(x, y) \land ￢∃y ∀x R(x, y)$ entails a contradiction. Maybe proving that $(∀x ∃y R(x, y) \land ￢∃y ∀x R(x, y)) \to \bot$?

Comment: We can not prove $\lnot(p\to q)$ when there are interpretations of $R$ which do make $p\to q$ hold.   Neither of $\exists x\forall y~xRy$ nor $\lnot\exists x\forall y~xRy$ is entailed by $\forall y\exists x~xRy$ alone.

Comment: We can't assign a truth value to $\lnot(p\to q)$? Is it not like propositional logic where every sentence is either true or false?

Comment: We cannot prove what truth value it holds when we do not know what $R$ means.

Comment: But we are able to prove $\exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y)$ regardless of what R means?

Comment: Yes.  As evidenced by doing so.

Comment: How do we know when something is unprovable without more information? (as opposed to lacking ability to finding a proof even if it happens to exist)

Comment: @user525966 You show that it is unprovable by providing a counter example ... which is exactly what you yourself already did in your own post!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes but that was just me looking for one, it's possible the problem is harder and not as obvious. I was hoping for more of a generalized strategy. It's really bothering me that we can say something definitive about the statement in one direction but not the other. The idea that we can't assign true/false values to some statements is grinding my gears and making me understand FOL less and less.

Comment: @user525966 Ha! Well, then here is something that will *really* grind your gears: it turns out that there *cannot* be a systematic method that can correctly classify *any* first-order logic argument as valid or invalid! This is called the 'undecidability of first-order logic'.

Comment: @Bram28 Aaaarrrrggggghhhhhhhh! So sometimes finding random counterexamples is the best we can do?

Comment: @user525966 Well, there are methods to systematically search for counterexamples (look for the 'truth tree method') ... and for simple enough arguments those methods will find a counterexample if there is one ... though only if the counterexample involves a finite number of objects ... and indeed these methods will not always found a counterexample when there is one.

Answer (score 1):

If $\exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y)$ then this means there is an $R$-maximal element, for example if $R$ is $\leq$ then this would mean there is a maximal element. Then sure, given an $R$-maximal element, then for any $x$ there is a $y$ $R$-greater than $x$, namely the $R$-maximal element. Think of the set $\{1,2,3\}$ ordered by $\leq$. There is an $\leq$-maximal element, namely $3$, and for any $x \in \{1,2,3\}$ we have $x \leq 3$. So yes

$\exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y) \rightarrow \forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y)$ is true.

In the other case, just because for every $x$ we have a $y$ which is $R$-greater than $x$, this doesn't imply there is an $R$-maximal element. Think of the set $\{1,2,3,..\}$ ordered by $\leq$. Given any $x$ I can find a $y$ greater than $x$, namely $x+1$, but still the set $\{1,2,..\}$ has no maximum. So yes

$\forall x\, \exists y\, R(x,y) \not\rightarrow \exists y\, \forall x\, R(x,y)$ is correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you said is correct: the order of the quantifiers matters. The only thing you miss is probably the fact that the proof you cited is not a proof of equivalence: in fact, the deductions are true if read from top to bottom, and not from bottom to top. In fact, the problematic step is that $∀y\ R(c, y) \implies R(c, d)$ but the converse is not true.